# Toggle Visibility of Paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

I'm not sure why I am having issues, except that this is my first week of ever seeing html and javascript, lol. But... My directions are to:

"Add the sentence: "Please push this to see more information about me.", where the word "this" is the text on a button (which is in the middle of the sentence). Implement the necessary JavaScript code so that when the button is clicked, a paragraph appears which gives some background information about you (where you were born or whatever). Each time the button is clicked it should toggle the display of that paragraph (causing it to be visible after the first click, hidden after the second, visible after the third, etc.). Further, the line with the button in it should change to the following when the text is visible: "Please push this to hide more information about me." The words "see" and "hide" should alternate as the button is clicked."

The trouble I am having is how to make those paragraphs visible when I click and not when I click again. I have tried several different things, based on other people's questions, and it just doesn't work. It will end up not toggling anything and leaving everything visible.

Thank you so much.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:#ADD8E6">


<h1>my Page</h1>

<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="hrg.jpg" width="280" height="280">

<p title="About me">
stuff about me... 
<br>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">Here is a link to learn more about HTML!</a>
<br>
<br>


</p>




<script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("hrgswitch")) {
        image.src = "hrg.jpg";
    } else {
        image.src = "hrgswitch.jpg";
    }
}



</script>
<script>

function myFunction(obj) {
var x = document.getElementById("me");


  if(("p3").style.visibility == "visible")
        ("p3").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    else
        ("p3").style.visibility = 'visible';
}

</script>
</head>
<body>


<p2> <br>
<br>
Please push this to see more information about me. <br>
 </p2>


<button id = "me" onclick = "myFunction("me")">this </button>

<p3>
<br> 
<br>
Please push this to see my list of courses."
<br>
<br>
<button>this </button>
<br>
more stuff about me <br>
</p3>



<br>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Course Name</td>
    <td>Date</td>       
    <td>Time</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Programming Paradigms</td>
    <td>Tuesday / Thursday</td>     
    <td>11:00-12:15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Computer Organization</td>
    <td>Tuesday / Thursday</td>     
    <td>9:30-10:45</td>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td>Linear Algebra</td>
    <td>Monday/Wednesday/Friday</td>        
    <td>11:50-12:40</td>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td>Combinatorics and Discrete Math</td>
    <td>Monday/Wednesday/Friday</td>        
    <td>8:35-9:25</td>
  </tr>

</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There seem to be several errors in your script. I'm working on a solution for you, but it's gonna take me some time.

Comment: `p2` and `p3` tags are not valid HTML. Also, javascript never does anything because it's trying to toggle the style and visibility of the STRING `"p3"` and not the ELEMENT.

Comment: First, Is this your exact HTML (or wrong copy/paste of page parts)? If this is real page, it is completely mess...and nothing will work properly in this context, so... rather fix all HTML errors first, then js scripting will be much easier. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've corrected most of your HTML code and made your function work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>About me</title>
        <style>
        body {
            background-color:#ADD8E6;
        }
        table {
            width:100%;
        }
        #p3 {
            display:none;
        }
        #myImage {
            width:280px;
            height:280px;
        }
        </style>
        <script language="javascript">
            function changeImage() {
                var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

                if (image.src.match("hrgswitch")) {
                    image.src = "hrg.jpg";
                } else {
                    image.src = "hrgswitch.jpg";
                }
            }

            function myFunction(obj) {
                if(obj == "me"){
                    if(document.getElementById("p3").style.display == "none" || document.getElementById("p3").style.display == ""){
                        document.getElementById("p3").style.display = "block";
                        document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "<br /><br />Please push this to hide more information about me.<br />";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("p3").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = "<br /><br />Please push this to see more information about me.<br />";
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>my Page</h1>
        <img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage();" src="hrg.jpg" />
        <p title="About me">
            stuff about me... 
            <br />
            <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">Here is a link to learn more about HTML!</a>
            <br />
            <br />
        </p>
        <p id="p2">
            <br />
            <br />
            Please push this to see more information about me. <br />
        </p>
        <button id="me" onclick ="myFunction('me');">this</button>
        <p id="p3">
            <br /> 
            <br />
            Please push this to see my list of courses."
            <br>
            <br>
            <button>this</button>
            <br>
            more stuff about me <br>
        </p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Course Name</td>
                <td>Date</td>       
                <td>Time</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Programming Paradigms</td>
                <td>Tuesday / Thursday</td>     
                <td>11:00-12:15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Computer Organization</td>
                <td>Tuesday / Thursday</td>     
                <td>9:30-10:45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Linear Algebra</td>
                <td>Monday/Wednesday/Friday</td>        
                <td>11:50-12:40</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Combinatorics and Discrete Math</td>
                <td>Monday/Wednesday/Friday</td>        
                <td>8:35-9:25</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you SO much. This definitely helped me understand everything I was doing more. I know mine was a mess, but like I said...this is my first week of ever seeing javascript or html. I modified this code to work perfectly with my assignment. My only other question (which I should probably make a new topic for? ) is how to, upon the click and visibility of the p3, to change the words "please push this to see more information about me." to "please push this to hide more information about me."

Comment: @Heather Well no. You shouldn't make a new topic for it as because one of the rules here is that we're not here to do your job for you. If you make a question, make sure you did your own research first and are able to show what you've tried yourself. Anyway. I'll edit my answer so it does what you need.

Answer (score 2):

A few small things first:

- You don't need separate script blocks for different functions
- p2 and p3 aren't real tags - if you need to select an individual paragraph, use a p tag with an id

  ```
  <p id="p3">Please push...</p>
  ```

  and in your javascript you'd target it like this:

  ```
  var p3 = document.getElementById('p3');
  p3.style.visibility = 'visible'; // for example
  ```
- Right now you have some of your script executing before the things you're trying to target. That's not going to work. Try grouping all your script into one block and putting it after the relevant parts of markup (ie the button, paragraph, etc).

As another commenter pointed out, you're supposed to have the button inside the sentence, so fix that. And while you're at it, onclick handlers are generally frowned upon; give it an ID and bind to it in your script. Here's some pseudo code; I haven't filled in the functions to make the actual changes, just noted where they go.

```
<p>Please push <button id="toggle-button">this</button> 
to <span id="see-hide">see</span> more info about me.</p>

<p id="p3">This is the content that hides or shows depending on click</p>

<script>
  var btn = document.getElementById('toggle-button'),
      image = document.getElementById('myImage'),
      seeHide = document.getElementById('see-hide'),
      toggleableContent = document.getElementById('p3'),
      textIsShowing = false; // to keep track of whether the button has been toggled with this

 /* We can write one function to change the image, the text, 
    and hide/show content all at once */

 function toggleEverything() {

    if( textIsShowing == false ) {

        // change the image
        // change the seeHide span from "show" to "hide"
        // show the toggleableContent paragraph

      textIsShowing = true; // this way, the next click will know we've already clicked once
      return;               // we're done here
    }

   /* this is what happens if textIsShowing is true, 
       because the block above will be skipped */

     // change the image back
     // change the seeHide span from "hide" to "show"
     // hide the toggleableContent paragraph

    textIsShowing = false; // reset this state for the next click
    return;                // and we're done
}

// Now we need to bind this to the button
btn.onclick = toggleEverything();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you'd add the actual line of text with the button:

```
<p>
    Please push <button onclick="toggleParagraphVisible();">this</button>
    to <span id="textIsHidden">see</span> more info about me.
</p>
```

Next, make sure you actually have a paragraph to hide and unhide.

```
<p id="toggleParagraph" style="display:none;">Bio goes here.</p>
```

Finally, just add the javascript code:

```
function toggleParagraphVisible(){
    if(document.getElementById("textIsHidden").innerText == "see"){
        //If the sentence says "see more info"

        //First, change the sentence to read "hide more info"
        document.getElementById("textIsHidden").innerText = "hide";
        //Next, change the display on the paragraph to block,
        //which makes it visible
        document.getElementById("toggleParagraph").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        //If the sentence doesn't say "see more info", revert everything
        document.getElementById("textIsHidden").innerText = "see";
        document.getElementById("toggleParagraph").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Unless I did something stupid (which people will undoubtably point out), this should work. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
 <button id = "me" onclick = "myFunction('me')">this </button>
```